# Best way to programmatically configure network adapters in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, wmi

I have an application written in C# that needs to be able to configure the network adapters in Windows.  I have this basically working through WMI, but there are a couple of things I don't like about that solution:  sometimes the settings don't seem to stick, and when the network cable is not plugged in, errors are returned from the WMI methods, so I can't tell if they really succeeded or not.

I need to be able to configure all of the settings available through the network connections - Properties - TCP/IP screens.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You could use `Process` to fire off [netsh](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242468) commands to set all the properties in the network dialogs.

eg:
To set a static ipaddress on an adapter

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1
```

To set it to dhcp you'd use

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

To do it from C# would be

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "interface ip set address \"Local Area Connection\" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1");
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
```

Setting to static can take a good couple of seconds to complete so if you need to, make sure you wait for the process to exit.

Comment: Any idea of how to elevate this command to run with administrator permissions?

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically

Comment: one downside of this answer is that your nic name is not always "Local Area Connection" it can be different.

Comment: @MubasharAhmad One way to resolve that is to use NetworkInterface to get all interfaces names with ".Description", then let them choose from it. Afterwards, grab the ".Name" and pass that to the command string. At least, that's what I did.

Comment: how to set static DNS in same ProcessStartInfo

Comment: > Setting to static can take a good couple of seconds to complete so if you need to, make sure you wait for the process to exit.

Nothing official, but when you want to do something with the configured nic right after setting the IP, it's good to check the routing table to make sure that windows is ready for communication with the new network.

Answer (score 10):

With my code
SetIpAddress and SetDHCP

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the ip address.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nicName">Name of the nic.</param>
    /// <param name="ipAddress">The ip address.</param>
    /// <param name="subnetMask">The subnet mask.</param>
    /// <param name="gateway">The gateway.</param>
    /// <param name="dns1">The DNS1.</param>
    /// <param name="dns2">The DNS2.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static bool SetIpAddress(
        string nicName,
        string ipAddress,
        string subnetMask,
        string gateway = null,
        string dns1 = null,
        string dns2 = null)
    {
        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();

        NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        NetworkInterface networkInterface = interfaces.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == nicName);
        string nicDesc = nicName;

        if (networkInterface != null)
        {
            nicDesc = networkInterface.Description;
        }

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            if ((bool)mo["IPEnabled"] == true
                && mo["Description"].Equals(nicDesc) == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject newIP = mo.GetMethodParameters("EnableStatic");

                    newIP["IPAddress"] = new string[] { ipAddress };
                    newIP["SubnetMask"] = new string[] { subnetMask };

                    ManagementBaseObject setIP = mo.InvokeMethod("EnableStatic", newIP, null);

                    if (gateway != null)
                    {
                        ManagementBaseObject newGateway = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetGateways");

                        newGateway["DefaultIPGateway"] = new string[] { gateway };
                        newGateway["GatewayCostMetric"] = new int[] { 1 };

                        ManagementBaseObject setGateway = mo.InvokeMethod("SetGateways", newGateway, null);
                    }


                    if (dns1 != null || dns2 != null)
                    {
                        ManagementBaseObject newDns = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
                        var dns = new List<string>();

                        if (dns1 != null)
                        {
                            dns.Add(dns1);
                        }

                        if (dns2 != null)
                        {
                            dns.Add(dns2);
                        }

                        newDns["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = dns.ToArray();

                        ManagementBaseObject setDNS = mo.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", newDns, null);
                    }
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Sets the DHCP.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="nicName">Name of the nic.</param>
    public static bool SetDHCP(string nicName)
    {
        ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();

        NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        NetworkInterface networkInterface = interfaces.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == nicName);
        string nicDesc = nicName;

        if (networkInterface != null)
        {
            nicDesc = networkInterface.Description;
        }

        foreach (ManagementObject mo in moc)
        {
            if ((bool)mo["IPEnabled"] == true
                && mo["Description"].Equals(nicDesc) == true)
            {
                try
                {
                    ManagementBaseObject newDNS = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");

                    newDNS["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = null;
                    ManagementBaseObject enableDHCP = mo.InvokeMethod("EnableDHCP", null, null);
                    ManagementBaseObject setDNS = mo.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", newDNS, null);
                }
                catch
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Does this method work with wifi profiles?

Answer (score 3):

with the help of @PaulB's answers help

```
NetworkInterface[] nics = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "interface ip set address " + nics[0].Name + " static 192.168." + provider_ip + "." + index + " 255.255.255.0 192.168." + provider_ip + ".1 1");
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
p.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you the way the trojans do it, after having had to clean up after a few of them, is to set registry keys under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE. The main ones they set are the DNS ones and that approach definitely sticks which can be attested to by anyone who has ever been infected and can no longer get to windowsupdate.com, mcafee.com, etc.

Comment: "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE" doesn't exactly narrow down where to find the keys that matter. A bit more detail would make this answer actually useful.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this app. it is a complete application to set both wifi and ethernet ips

https://github.com/kamran7679/ConfigureIP