# Detecting internet connectivity and changing the default gateway programatically in .NET

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, ipv4

We have 3 lease lines for internet connectivity in our office. When there are issues with internet connectivity, the office staff has to go to RUN --> ncpa.cpl --> Right click on network --> select properties --> TCP/IPV4 --> Change default gateway value to shift between lease lines.

I would like to develop a .NET program that is able to detect at runtime the internet connectivity and change the gateway.

I donot want to use programs available on internet, rather, create my own simple application. Please provide some usefull reference for this, I have experience in .NET coding.

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look on these websites. It might help you to some extent:

[Set network configuration programmatically c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7670980/set-network-configuration-programmatically-c-sharp)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/391e01cf-4558-4375-aa1a-386ed4e3e00a/change-host-ip-address-subnet-mask-and-gateway-settings-using-c-application?forum=csharpgeneral

Comment: OK, thanks, thats about changing configuration, any idea how to detect conenctivity.

Comment: Just use the plain function
System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()
that return true of false if the connection is up.

Comment: I found this in following link, you can use it for further clarifications: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2521569/how-to-detect-working-internet-connection-in-c

Comment: One more reference: http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?738069-Detecting-Internet-Connections-from-Your-C-Code