# How to install new network adapter using Java on Windows

Tags: java, windows, networking, pppoe

I ought to create a program for a local ISP. They need a program that would automatically install new broadband adapter (with certain configuration) in Windows XP and later. I'd like to do it using Java, but if it wont be doable I could also use C#.
I'm looking for a way how to do it but I haven't found anything useful so far.
I thought I could be able to do it with "netsh" through executing commands but I couldn't find a way to actually create new interface using the netsh.

Thanks for all your help

edit: so I actually found that i need to create a PPPoE connection. 
The best I can get so far is to make a popup window with rasphone -a ... Isn't there any way to do it just with code? :/ I'm searching Google like mad but can't find anything...

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this [article](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rafaelwo/microsoft-loopback-adapter-programmatically-installation-and-configuration/) and this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/689230/best-way-to-programmatically-configure-network-adapters-in-net)?
The latter is related to C#, but it should give you a hint on what to do.

Comment: Thanks. Actually I found out that even when I manually install the PPPoE broadband I still cant find it within the netsh... Any ideas? I need to instal the PPPoE SOMEHOW and then edit the settings.

Comment: Nope, at the moment I don't have a Windows box to try. Something in the event viewer?

Comment: Ok I found that it could be SOMEHOW achieved with RAS (Rasdial/rasphone) tools on WIN, but I still cant manage to add the PPPoE using ONLY cmd...