# C# - enable / disable DHCP

Tags: c#, networking, dhcp

I'm looking for a way to to enable or disable DHCP using C# on a given network adapter. looking for the easiest solution.

Thank you.

Comment: What's an "essayist solution"? Did you mean "easiest solution"?

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/689230/best-way-to-programmatically-configure-network-adapters-in-net/760611#760611

Comment: @user27811 This question is about disabling DHCP, not disabling the adapter itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `Process` to fire off [netsh](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/242468) commands to set all the properties in the network dialogs.

eg:
To set a static ipaddress on an adapter

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1
```

To set it to dhcp you'd use

```
netsh interface ip set address "Local Area Connection" dhcp
```

To do it from C# would be

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "interface ip set address \"Local Area Connection\" static 192.168.0.10 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1 1");
p.StartInfo = psi;
p.Start();
```

Setting to static can take a good couple of seconds to complete so if you need to, make sure you wait for the process to exit.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe..

```
        const string networcCardName = "[00000007] Intel(R) Ethernet Connection I217-LM"; //Example NIC name
        var management = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration");
        var moc = management.GetInstances();

        foreach (var o in moc)
        {
            var mo = (ManagementObject) o;
            if (!(bool) mo["IPEnabled"]) continue;
            if (!mo["Caption"].Equals(networcCardName)) continue;

            var ndns = mo.GetMethodParameters("SetDNSServerSearchOrder");
            ndns["DNSServerSearchOrder"] = null;
            var enableDhcp = mo.InvokeMethod("EnableDHCP", null, null);
            var setDns = mo.InvokeMethod("SetDNSServerSearchOrder", ndns, null);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks also a  good option, voted for other due to its simplicity in understanding the code.