# .NET WPF Process.Start() not working on Vista and Windows 7

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, windows-7, windows-vista

I have WPF application.
After testing my app on Windows7 and realized that opening help does not work.

Basically to open chm help file I call:

```
Process.Start("help.chm");
```

And nothing happens. I have also tried my app on Vista SP1, same result. 
I'm admin in both OS'es

I have googled this problem, but have not found solution to it.

Is there way to solve this problem?

Have you experienced this types of incompatibilities.

Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried ShellExecute ?

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("shell32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        static extern bool ShellExecuteEx(ref SHELLEXECUTEINFO lpExecInfo);

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
public struct SHELLEXECUTEINFO
{
    public int cbSize;
    public uint fMask;
    public IntPtr hwnd;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpVerb;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpFile;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpParameters;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpDirectory;
    public int nShow;
    public IntPtr hInstApp;
    public IntPtr lpIDList;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)]
    public string lpClass;
    public IntPtr hkeyClass;
    public uint dwHotKey;
    public IntPtr hIcon;
    public IntPtr hProcess;
}
```

and you can try to start process with :

```
        SHELLEXECUTEINFO info = new SHELLEXECUTEINFO();
        info.cbSize = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.SizeOf(info);
        info.lpVerb = "open";
        info.lpFile = "help.chm";
        info.nShow = 5;
        info.fMask = 12;

        ShellExecuteEx(ref info);
```

(http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/shell32.ShellExecuteEx)

Comment: What's the difference between pinvoking ShellExecute directly and calling ProcessStart(ProcessStartInfo) with UseShellExecute=true ?

Answer (score 1):

This [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically) should help you.  Also, here's a [pretty detailed article](http://codefromthe70s.org/vistatutorial.aspx) on UAC and how to elevate.

Answer (score 1):

Is it just .chm files? If so it may not be opening because, by default, chm files in untrusted locations are blocked. See: [KB902225](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/902225). From [this article](http://intellects.in/2008/11/06/utility-to-recursively-unblock-files-downloaded-from-internet/) it appears that you may be able to unblock them programmatically, even if it's just by launching Sysinternals streams.exe first (as referenced in the article).