# Problem with Killing windows explorer?

Tags: c#, windows, process, explorer

I need to kill windows explorer's process (explorer.exe), for that

lets say i use a native NT method TerminateProcess

It works but the problem is that the explorer starts again, may be windows is doing that, anyway. When i kill explorer.exe with windows task manager, it doesn't come back, its stays killed.

I want to do whatever taskmanager is doing through my application.

Edit:
Thanks to @sblom i solved it, a quick tweak in the registry did the trick. Although its a clever hack, apparently taskmnager has a cleaner way of doing that, that said, i've decided to go with @sblom's way for now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The "real" solution. (Complete program. Tested to work on Windows 7.)

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ExplorerZap
{
    class Program
    {
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool PostMessage(int hWnd, uint Msg, int wParam, int lParam);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int hwnd;
            hwnd = FindWindow("Progman", null);
            PostMessage(hwnd, /*WM_QUIT*/ 0x12, 0, 0);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work. It closes the desktop and taskbar, but doesn't actually stop the explorer.exe process.

Answer (score 15):

From [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc939703.aspx):

You can set the registry key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AutoRestartShell` to 0, and it will no longer auto-restart.

Comment: @sblom Great ! thanks man it works, one little mystery although your workaround works perfectly. taskmanager does not seem to mess with registry settings like this. Now please please dont take it personally i was just wondering. Your answer was a life saver, as i needed it urgently

Comment: @sblom just to give other people a chance to solve that taskmanager mystery i leave your anwser as un-accepted for a little while. I'll do that eventually !

Answer (score 5):

Here's another solution to this problem - instead api calls it uses an external tool shipped with windows (at least Win 7 Professional):

```
    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static void ForceKill(this Process process)
        {
            using (Process killer = new Process())
            {
                killer.StartInfo.FileName = "taskkill";
                killer.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/f /PID {0}", process.Id);
                killer.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                killer.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                killer.Start();
                killer.WaitForExit();
                if (killer.ExitCode != 0)
                {
                    throw new Win32Exception(killer.ExitCode);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I know that Win32Exception may not be the best Exception, but this method acts more or less like Kill - with the exception that it actually kills windows explorer.

I've added it as an extension method, so you can use it directly on Process object:

```
    foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer"))
    {
        process.ForceKill();
    }
```

You must first ensure that the taskkill tool is available on production environment (it seems that it's been for a while with windows: https://web.archive.org/web/20171016213040/http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/taskkill.mspx?mfr=true).

**EDIT:** Original link dead, replaced with cache from Internet Archive Wayback Machine. Updated documentation for Windows 2012/2016 can be found at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/taskkill

Answer (score 2):

What you probably need to do is instead of using TerminateProcess, post a WM_QUIT message to the explorer windows and main thread. It's a bit involved, but I found this page which has some example code that might help you along:

http://www.replicator.org/node/100

Windows will automatically restart explorer.exe after a TerminateProcess so that it restarts in the case of a crash termination.

Answer (score 0):

I have some researches and these are reslts:

> Windows will restart `explorer` after it closed -*except by Task Manager*-.

So you should change the related `RegistryKey`:

```
RegistryKey regKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Default).OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
if (regKey.GetValue("AutoRestartShell").ToString() == "1")
    regKey.SetValue("AutoRestartShell", 0, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

For changing a registry key the program should run as administrator:

- You can show UAC prompt to user to run application as administrator as explaining in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818776/4519059).
  And if UAC is turned off I direct you to this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2823884/4519059).
- You can embed a manifest file in the `exe`, which will cause Windows Seven to always run the program as an administrator, As explaining in this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2818321/4519059).
- You should know you can't force your process starts as administrator; so you can run your process inside your process as another process! You can use this [blog post](http://antscode.blogspot.nl/2011/02/running-clickonce-application-as.html) or this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10905713/4519059).
- You can also use `reg` command with this [Microsoft Windows Documentation].[6](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/reg.mspx?mfr=true).

After setting that -*restarting explorer*- off: This code can close `explorer` :

```
Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
foreach (Process p in ps)
    p.Kill();
```

Comment: I add my answer just as a result of what I done for same problem ;).