# Kill Explorer process

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file

Strange, but perhaps I am handling it the incorrect way - I need to quite simply check if explorer.exe is running, and if so kill it. However, the way I am currently achieving this, explorer.exe simply restarts after I kill it.

Normal taskkill through batch works fine though, does C# do something different?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Process[] prcChecker = Process.GetProcessesByName("explorer");
    if (prcChecker.Length > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Explorer running");
        foreach (Process p in prcChecker)
        {
            p.Kill();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Explorer is not running");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a duplicate question! Solution: 
http://superuser.com/questions/511914/why-does-explorer-restart-automatically-when-i-kill-it-with-process-kill

Comment: How is that superuser material? It's C#.... I get a downvote for not looking on the wrong site :(

Comment: indeed ;) but hey, they answered it :)

Comment: considering that googling for 1s reveals the answer to the EXACT same question... yes

Comment: Maybe, but look here: @DanBarzilay, the accepted answer to this question doesn't work, and the others are not very helpful either. Please don't close. – Thomas Levesque Nov 27 '12 at 13:49 Would also require elevated privileges to execute.

Comment: oh weird... because it does work for me, did this few months ago :) that is actually why I already knew the post on superuser ;)

Comment: please take a look  at this  link  on  how to this efficiently 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570244/problem-with-killing-windows-explorer

Comment: So if it's working with Batch properly, why don't you execute the batch file via C#?`

Answer (score 2):

That's because Windows takes care of restarting `explorer.exe` if it happens to die.

It is possible to delay this behavior (the setup of tortoisegit does this, for example), but it's not recommended - users are going to be pissed.

Answer (score 2):

Although not C# way but you can alternatively try to set the registry key `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\AutoRestartShell` to 0 to stop the auto restart.

**EDIT:-**

Try this in C#:-

```
RegistryKey ourKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
ourKey = ourKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon", true);
ourKey.SetValue("AutoRestartShell", 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to kill the Process with exit code `1` .

Sorry i dont have any example code because i am not a C# programmer but in my application it worked just fine.

I used the C++ Function:

[TerminateProcess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-terminateprocess)