# How to run another app as administrator on Windows XP

Tags: c#, .net, windows-xp, uac, elevation

I used the application manifest file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-c-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7) to have a part of my application running with elevated privileges (which it needs).
So when needed, the main program just invokes a small assembly using Process.Start which then handles the task for which admin rights are required.

However, how can I do the same thing on Windows XP?
It seems XP just ignores this manifest and runs the small assembly in the current user context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268059/how-to-compile-program-that-will-launch-an-exe-as-administrator/3268472#3268472) does just what I need:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("path", "args");
processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";

using (Process process = new Process())
{
   process.StartInfo = processStartInfo;
   process.Start();
   process.WaitForExit();
}
```

So in fact you need to set "runas" on ProcessStartInfo.Verb.
With the attached manifest this code now works fine on Windows XP, Vista and 7.

**Update:**
See also [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3925065/correct-way-to-deal-with-uac-in-c/3925167#3925167). This is basically the same code, just using arguments as well.

Comment: problem is that XP SP3's Runas dialog has running as the current user ticked by default, and even ticks "protect my computer and data from unauthorized program activity" - this actually reduces privileges!

Comment: @eug : quite an old topic but I have the same problem today under Windows XP. Remove 'processStartInfo.Verb = "runas";'
But keep it for Windows 7+ (not checked under Vista)

Answer (score 3):

Windows XP does not have UAC.

You need to call `Process.Start` with the login credentials of a user with administrative priviliges.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [`runas`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/runas.mspx) command.