# How to set "run as administrator" privileged in visual studio 2010 setup project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, exe, setup-project

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to force my .NET App to run as administrator on Windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2818179/how-to-force-my-net-app-to-run-as-administrator-on-windows-7)

My application is based on `Windows-Thread`. So it must run as a `administrator` privileged, To run the application every user have to do right click and choose "run as administrator" option.

But i don't want to do that, is there any way to change the `setup project` so that when application installed on `windows-machine` it sets it privileged with run as administrator and  every time when users run it on his local machine , it permanently with run as administrator option.

System: `XP`, `Win-7`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [add/modify the manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb756929.aspx)

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="true"/>
```

**EDIT**

See this question and answer to see how to do this for Windows XP: [How to run another app as administrator on Windows XP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715876/how-to-run-another-app-as-administrator-on-windows-xp)

**EDIT**

For ClickOnce you could use a trick as mentioned in [this blogpost](http://antscode.blogspot.nl/2011/02/running-clickonce-application-as.html) by starting a second process as admin.

Comment: Thanks for replying, Where i found the `mainfest` file?

Comment: Read the MSDN page I linked to. You can add it in the project of the program.

Comment: I added info on fixing this for Windows XP.

Comment: I added it but it shows me an error:
`ClickOnce does not supported the request execution level 'recquireAdministrator'`

Comment: Please look at the `manifest`file: http://pastebin.com/ugDp3sfF

Comment: Officially ClickOnce does not support "run as admin" But there is a trick: http://antscode.blogspot.nl/2011/02/running-clickonce-application-as.html Next time please add to your question that you are using clickonce.