# How can I compile a c program as administrator privileges without manual settings like many other applications?

Tags: c

whenever I want to run a c program as admin in windows, I will right click the program and click run as administrator without this manual , can I compile the c code to ask the user for admin privileges like most of other application.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main()
{
    FILE* fp;

    fp=fopen("c:/TEXT.c","w");

    if(fp==NULL)
     {
        perror("FILE ERROR");
        exit(1);
     }
     printf("Sucessfully file created");

     getch();

  return 0;
}
```

output:(non admin)

```
  FILE ERROR: Permission denied

  --------------------------------
  Process exited after 0.04759 seconds with return value 1
  Press any key to continue . . .
```

output:(as admin)

```
  Sucessfully file created
```

Comment: Maybe helpfull: https://stackoverflow.com/q/3268059/1606345

Comment: Did you search for "administration rights elevation" or such? What Win32 API calls did you find? Which did you try?