# Win7, SP1, UAC, administrative privileges & elevation - problem!

Tags: .net, windows-7, process, uac

Folks,

Big problem that I'm not sure how to address.  Seems that Win7 SP1 broke my application.  My scenario used to work!

I have a Win C# .NET 4.0 application with a manifest that requests administrative privileges via app.manifest line:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

I also am starting a new thread in my application via the following lines of code:

```
Process certMaker = new Process();
certMaker.StartInfo.FileName = makeCertExe;
certMaker.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
certMaker.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
certMaker.Start();
certMaker.WaitForExit();
```

This used to work no problems, but now it no longer runs under elevated privileges.  Just to be sure, I've decorated the method with:

```
[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"BUILTIN\Administrators")]
```

but am only getting a "Request for principal permission failed" error.

Any help?  What has changed in SP1 that could'ev caused this?  Our application is not signed yet due to high costs.

I tried to have UAC off or ON at any level, I trued to set compatibility mode set from XP through Win7 and nothing.

I've enabled full audit reports for any sorts of security failures in the OS.  Here is what I think I'm getting everytime I try to run my command:

```
A handle to an object was requested.

Subject:
    Security ID:        LOCAL SERVICE
    Account Name:       LOCAL SERVICE
    Account Domain:     NT AUTHORITY
    Logon ID:       0x3e5

Object:
    Object Server:      PlugPlayManager
    Object Type:        Security
    Object Name:        PlugPlaySecurityObject
    Handle ID:      0x0

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x2dc
    Process Name:       C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe

Access Request Information:
    Transaction ID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
    Accesses:       Unknown specific access (bit 1)

    Access Reasons:     -
    Access Mask:        0x2
    Privileges Used for Access Check:   -
    Restricted SID Count:   0
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Why `UseShellExecute=false`? If you make it `true`, it will use your manifest. I know you say it used to work, but in my experience you have to use ShellExecute to get your manifest taken into account.

This is independent of signing, btw - that just determines whether you get the scary orange dialog with question marks on it and Unknown Publisher or a slightly less scary one that names your firm.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I've tried following your directions to no avail!  I've also looked at this thread for the verb usage of "runas".  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596259/elevating-privileges-doesnt-work-with-useshellexecute-false

Comment: ok, let's try some things. Go double click makecert.exe. Does it ask to elevate? If not, it's the manifest. If yes, it's the way you're launching it.

Comment: UAC is off.  It does not ask to elevate.  But it runs OK from a command prompt

Comment: Here is what's interesting, I've enabled detailed audit reports on pretty much everything under Audit Policies... I'm adding the report to the main body of this post