# Getting CMD output via Process.Start with UseShellExecute = true in C#

Tags: c#, cmd

I need to run an elevated command in my c# application and get the output.

I'm creating a new `System.Diagnostics.Process` instance, coupled with a new `System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo` instance.

The command is being sent to `cmd.exe`, and unfortunately may require elevated user access (meaning `UseShellExecute = true` and `Verb = "runas"` must be present).

As a result of using `UseShellExecute = true`, `RedirectStandardOutput` will not work.

It's important I record the output of the command, but the only way I can see of getting this is adding something like `> output.txt` to the argument list, then calling `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` to read the result.

Can anyone think of less hacky way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Redirect standard output and prompt for UAC with ProcessStartInfo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660014/redirect-standard-output-and-prompt-for-uac-with-processstartinfo)