# Start a program that is in Program Files folder

Tags: java, runtime, exe

I want to start an exe with java.
This exe is in the Program Files (x86) folder and when I try :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CodFiscExtractor\\MySQLServer\\MySqlStart.exe");
```

the console displays me this error :

```
CreateProcess error=740, The requested operation requires elevation
```

What I should do?

EDIT : this is not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660014/redirect-standard-output-and-prompt-for-uac-with-processstartinfo), because i'm asking **java**

Comment: Did you try elevation?

Comment: @RobertColumbia no, how i can?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Redirect standard output and prompt for UAC with ProcessStartInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660014/redirect-standard-output-and-prompt-for-uac-with-processstartinfo)

Comment: @JeffreySamarziya that is not a duplicate as this is a Java question and that one is WPF. It's certainly related and could be helpful, but not a dupe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved, simply I writed like this :

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\CodFiscExtractor\\MySQLServer\\MySqlStart.exe\"");
```

Now I don't have error, but I am insterested to don't show UAC window, because `MySqlStart.exe` starts with admin privileges.