# The requested operation requires elevation

Tags: c#

I am trying to run an exe file from another user account name, it shows following error

```
    System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The requested operation requires an elevation
at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithCreateProcess(ProcessStartInfo startInfo) at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
    at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
```

Here is my code

```
ProcessStartInfo pro = new ProcessStartInfo(application);
pro.UseShellExecute = false;
pro.Verb = "runas";
pro.WorkingDirectory = workingdirectory;
pro.RedirectStandardInput = true;
pro.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
pro.CreateNoWindow = true;

Process process = Process.Start(pro);
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: My very initial question is whether you've tried running it (your app) as an administrator?

Comment: yes..I started it as an admin only

Comment: I remember reading somewhere that `runas` requires `UseShellExecute = true`. Does it work if you set `UseShellExecute` to `true`?

Comment: when i assign it to true, it shows "UseShellExecute must be false in order to start the process as a user

Answer (score 19):

Unfortunately, you cannot do

- run with elevated permissions and
- redirect input/output

simultaneously.

Reason:

- `Verb` is only recognized when `UseShellExecute = true`, but
- redirecting IO requires `UseShellExecute = false`.

More information:

- [Elevating privileges doesn't work with UseShellExecute=false](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596259/elevating-privileges-doesnt-work-with-useshellexecute-false)

I guess in your situation you will have to skip using `runas`, but rather ensure that *your* application is already started with the correct user account/permissions. This should work, since [processes started by elevated processes "inherit" elevation](https://superuser.com/q/163361/14517).

Comment: I have to run with elevated permissions only ....i dont want to redirect input/output...can u suggest me the code..@Heinzi

Comment: There's a way to write in the manifest that an application should always run as an admin, right? I don't remember how because it's been a while, but that'd probably be a good thing to do for this. I'm sure there are places documenting it.

Comment: @user3797438: If you don't want to redirect input/output, why do you set `RedirectStandardInput` to `true`? Surely, every line in your code has a good reason for being there, right?