# C#: Process.Start - The requested operation requires elevation

Tags: c#, process

I am trying to run an `exe` file from my own machine:

```
string versionInFolder = @"c:\test.exe";
public void Install(string versionInFolder)
        {
            ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                CreateNoWindow = true,
                UseShellExecute = false,
                FileName = versionInFolder,
                WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            };
            using (Process process = Process.Start(processStartInfo))
            {
                process.WaitForExit();
            }
        }
```

This file exist and can run manually but i got this `error`:

> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: 'The requested operation
>   requires elevation'

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25600448/the-requested-operation-requires-elevation) post but did not understand the reason for this `error` and how to solve it.

Comment: means you need admin right to access files directly under c drive. Either run your c# program as admin or disable UAC (not recommended)

Comment: This file is not on C drive

Comment: in your code it clearly says c:\test.exe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run your programm as admininistrator.
Check that first.

And if that doesn't work, or if you're the administrator, try to move your file in another place.