# How can I programmatically turn off or on 'Windows Features'

Tags: c#, powershell, io-redirection, elevated-privileges

When I try to update Windows features; When I update UseShellExecute to "true"; "The Process object must have the UseShellExecute property set to false in order to redirect IO streams." I get an error. When I set it to False; Unable to update. How can I do it ?   Do you have any other suggestions?

```
 static void InstallIISSetupFeature()
        {
            var featureNames = new List<string>() {

                 "IIS-WebServerRole",
                "IIS-WebServer",
                "IIS-CommonHttpFeatures",
                "IIS-HttpErrors",
                "IIS-HttpRedirect",
                "IIS-ApplicationDevelopment",
                "IIS-Security",
                "IIS-RequestFiltering",
                "IIS-NetFxExtensibility",
                "IIS-NetFxExtensibility45",
                "IIS-HealthAndDiagnostics",
                "IIS-HttpLogging",
                "IIS-LoggingLibraries",
                "IIS-RequestMonitor",
                "IIS-HttpTracing",
                "IIS-URLAuthorization",
                "IIS-IPSecurity",
                "IIS-Performance",
                "IIS-HttpCompressionDynamic",
                "IIS-WebServerManagementTools",
                "IIS-ManagementScriptingTools",
                "IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility",
                "IIS-Metabase",
                "IIS-HostableWebCore","IIS-StaticContent", 
                "IIS-DefaultDocument",
                "IIS-DirectoryBrowsing",
                "IIS-WebDAV",
                "IIS-WebSockets",
                "IIS-ApplicationInit",
                "IIS-ASPNET",
                "IIS-ASPNET45",
                "IIS-ASP",
                "IIS-CGI",
                "IIS-ISAPIExtensions",
                "IIS-ISAPIFilter",
                "IIS-ServerSideIncludes",
                "IIS-CustomLogging",
                "IIS-BasicAuthentication",
                "IIS-HttpCompressionStatic",
                "IIS-ManagementConsole",
                "IIS-ManagementService",
                "IIS-WMICompatibility",
                "IIS-LegacyScripts",
                "IIS-LegacySnapIn",
                "IIS-FTPServer",
                "IIS-FTPSvc",
                "IIS-FTPExtensibility",
                "IIS-CertProvider",
                "IIS-WindowsAuthentication",
                "IIS-DigestAuthentication",
                "IIS-ClientCertificateMappingAuthentication",
                "IIS-IISCertificateMappingAuthentication",
                "IIS-ODBCLogging",
                "NetFx4-AdvSrvs",
                "NetFx4Extended-ASPNET45",
                "NetFx3",
                "WAS-WindowsActivationService",
                "WCF-HTTP-Activation",
                "WCF-HTTP-Activation45",
                "WCF-MSMQ-Activation45",
                "WCF-NonHTTP-Activation",
                "WCF-Pipe-Activation45",
                "WCF-TCP-Activation45",
                "WCF-TCP-PortSharing45",
                "WCF-Services45",
            };
               ManagementObjectSearcher obj = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_OperatingSystem");
                foreach (ManagementObject wmi in obj.Get())
                {
                    string Name = wmi.GetPropertyValue("Caption").ToString();
                    Name = Regex.Replace(Name.ToString(), "[^A-Za-z0-9 ]", "");
                    if (Name.Contains("Server 2008 R2") || Name.Contains("Windows 7"))
                    {
                        featureNames.Add("IIS-ASPNET");
                        featureNames.Add("IIS-NetFxExtensibility");
                        featureNames.Add("WCF-HTTP-Activation");
                        featureNames.Add("WCF-MSMQ-Activation");
                        featureNames.Add("WCF-Pipe-Activation");
                        featureNames.Add("WCF-TCP-Activation");
                        featureNames.Add("WCF-TCP-Activation");
                    }
                    string Version = (string)wmi["Version"];
                    string Architecture = (string)wmi["OSArchitecture"];
                }         
            foreach (var featureName in featureNames)
            {
                Run(string.Format("dism/online/Enable-Feature:{0}", featureName));
            }
         
        }  
        static void Run(string arguments)
        {
            try
            {
                string systemPath = Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%"), "system32");

                var dism = new Process();
                dism.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = systemPath;
                dism.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
                dism.StartInfo.FileName = "dism.exe";
                dism.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";

                dism.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                dism.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                dism.Start();
                var result = dism.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
                dism.WaitForExit();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }

        }`
```

I tried to update the feature with dism.exe and cmd.exe, when it gave an authorization error, I used the Verb property
`

Comment: It sound like you are not running Powershell as Admin.  Either create a shortcut for Powershell and right click to select Admin or from Start Button type Powershell and right click on ICON to select Admin.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71344930/10024425 - it shows how to use an application manifest file along with "runas" to run Process elevated.  For `dism.StartInfo.FileName`, you may consider using the fully-qualified filename. Why are you passing `dism/online/Enable-Feature:...` as an argument? Remove `dism` from the argument string. See [Enable or Disable Windows Features Using DISM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/enable-or-disable-windows-features-using-dism?view=windows-11).

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://github.com/user09938/PowerShell-Dism and https://github.com/user09938/Process-Dism

Answer (score 0):

- Since the use of `.Verb = "RunAs"` requires `.UseShellExecute = true`, and since the latter cannot be combined with `RedirectStandardOutput = true`, you cannot *directly* capture the elevated process' output in memory.

  - It seems that **the system itself, by security-minded design, prevents a non-elevated process from directly capturing an elevated process' output**.
- The **workaround** is to **launch the target executable (`dism.exe`, in your case) *indirectly*, via a *shell*, and then use the latter's redirection feature (`>`)** to capture the target executable's output (invariably) in a *file*, as shown below.

```cs
string systemPath = Path.Combine(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%windir%"), "system32");

// Create a temp. file to capture the elevated process' output in.
string tempOutFile = Path.GetTempFileName();

var dism = new Process();
dism.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = systemPath;
// Use cmd.exe as the executable, and pass it a command line via /c
dism.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe" ;
// Use a ">" redirection to capture the elevated process' output.
// Use "2> ..." to also capture *stderr* output.
// Append "2>&1" to capture *both* stdout and stderr in the file targeted with ">"
dism.StartInfo.Arguments = 
  String.Format(
    "/c {0} {1} > \"{2}\"", 
    "dism.exe", arguments, tempOutFile
  );
dism.StartInfo.Verb = "RunAs";
dism.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;

dism.Start();
dism.WaitForExit();
// Read the temp. file in which the output was captured...
var result = File.ReadAllText(tempOutFile);
// ... and delete it.
File.Delete(tempOutFile);
```

Comment: It is actually possible to capture `dism` output without setting `UseShellExecute = true;`.

Comment: @user9938, not if you want to run _with elevation_ (`.Verb = "RunAs"`), which is the premise of the question.

Answer (score 0):

First, you can use `WindowsPrincipal::IsInRole()` to check if you're running elevated.
See [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsprincipal.isinrole?view=net-7.0) for details.

Second, this may be one of those cases where using native PS is easier than the cmdlet approach (admittedly, still not great).

If the script is supposed to run on clients as well as server operating systems: use `Get-WmiObject` or `Get-CimInstance` to get a reference to what you're running on. ActiveDirectory also has that information (in operatingSystem attribute).

For servers use `Get-WindowsFeature` in ServerManager module.
For clients use `Get-WindowsOptionalFeature` with switch `-Online` in DISM module which, if you indeed need to support OSes older than 6.3.xxxx, can be copied over from a machine that has it and added to `$Env:Path` **before** C:\Windows and C:\Windows\System32.

For either platform just pass the list of features to configure.

If in a (binary) cmdlet you have to call external tools then the advantage of them is mostly gone. It may be possible to access Windows CBS using a managed API to avoid this but even then the script based approach gets more results faster, especially since you can just just put together a quick wrapper around `dism.exe` .