# C# how to Cancel Windows Shutdown

Tags: c#

I want to my application can prevent from windows shutting down.
I know that there is a system command to do that. But don't work for my program.

```
private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CloseReason.Equals(CloseReason.WindowsShutDown))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Cancelling Windows shutdown");
        string cmd = "shutdown /a";
        Process.Start(cmd);// for executing system command.
    }
}
```

Comment: Try with shutdown -a

Comment: The days that this was still possible are over and done with, Vista put an end to it.  Won't be missed.

Comment: This may need to be run as an administrative user. Add an `Application Manifest File` to your project and modify it so that your project requires administrator privileges to run. Also, that's not the correct usage of [System.Diagnostics.Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=net-7.0). The `Filename` should be the fully-qualified path. Then for `Arguments` you'll pass `/a`. See [ProcessStartInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo?view=net-7.0). You may (or may not) need to set `UseShellExecute = true;`

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71344930/10024425

Comment: Do you want to prevent automatic shutdown while the user is inactive or manual shutdown initiated by the user?

Comment: @DanielA.White the duplicate link is incorrect, that refers to *preventing* a shutdown from being triggered, not cancelling it once started.