Start a process as administrator in C#
I want to start a process as administrator in C#, but it doesn't work.
Can someone help me?
Thanks.
ProcessStartInfo cmd = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    Arguments = "/C dism /online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:TelnetClient",
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    Verb = "runas"
};
 Process.Start(cmd);

I tried to use this code, but it doesn't work.
Verb = "runas"


research the proper command to feed into "FileName"

You need both the flags setup. UseShellExecute = true and Verb = "runas"  to execute process as administrator.

This will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programmatically

You need to provide the user (UAC) details if you want to run it as admin with different account on the server. You might need to provide username, password, Domain etc. as well. While Testing from VS Debug make sure you have open VS with Admin privileges.

Out of curiosity why are you shelling out to cmd.exe to call dism.exe, why don't you call dism.exe directly?

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71344930/10024425
