# C# Process start powershell and execute command, doesn't have admin permission

Tags: c#, powershell, process

First of all, the commands that i want to execute are `get-vm` and `start-vm`, which are need admin permission.
In my app , i will check the hyper-v vm state to see it **Running** or **Off**. thus , i need to invoke `get-vm {vmName}` the get the state. after got the vm state , if the state is **Off**, then i will invoke `start-vm {vmName}` to start the vm.

secondly, i use **Process** to start **PowerShell** with **UserName and Password**.
the code is below:

```
        var tmp = CShortPath.GetShortPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), System.IO.Path.GetRandomFileName()));

        var processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            Verb = "runas",
            LoadUserProfile = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true,

            FileName = "powershell.exe",
            //Arguments = "Start-VM -name 'win11-Lite'",
            Arguments = $"get-VM 'win11-Lite' >{tmp}",
            RedirectStandardOutput = false,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            UserName = "{AdminUserName}",
            Password = MakePwd("AdminPwd")

        };
        Process.Start(processInfo);
```

as you see, when executed , the output file  **{tmp}** is empty, and there will not display UAC Permission dialog.
what should do ?

Comment: What is the exitcode of the resulting process?

Comment: `UseShellExecute` needs to be `true` - see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3596259/elevating-privileges-doesnt-work-with-useshellexecute-false)

Comment: @stuartd, no UserName/Password needs  UseShellExecute = false

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, the exitcode is 1. no error.

Comment: @goldii exitcode 1 corresponds with a conflict between the requested verb and lack of shell execute :)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, even-if i remove Verb = "runas", the exit code is still 1.  please give more details. thanks.

Comment: Don't use `runas` in the first place. You aren't making a DDE call so that can only cause bugs. You don't need to start PowerShell itself, you can host it inside your application, with `PowerShell.Create`. Check the [PowerShell Host Quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/windows-powershell-host-quickstart?view=powershell-7.3)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, then you will got an error "Exception thrown: 'System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInException' in System.Management.Automation.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.PSSnapInException' occurred in System.Management.Automation.dll
System error."

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, this is demo code from mcrosoft , which caused error;    `          using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("get-process"))
            {
                WriteLog("Process              HandleCount");
                WriteLog("--------------------------------");
                foreach (PSObject retx in powershell.Invoke())
                {
                    var txt = $"{retx.Members["ProcessName"].Value} - {retx.Members["HandleCount"].Value}";

                    WriteLog(txt);
                }
            }

            return;`

Comment: That means you have no permissions to use Powershell. Because the sample works just fine. Is that why you try to pass a username and password?  You can't just pass a password to `Process` to start it a process as another user. That's not how Windows works.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, when execute demo code , it will failed .  PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Get-Process").AddParameter("Name", "PowerShell").Invoke();  i don't know why. the code is from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/hosting/windows-powershell-host-quickstart?view=powershell-7.3

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, the PowerShell code must be run from an _elevated_ process, hence goldii's attempt to use `.Verb = "RunAs"`. The problem is that this fundamentally _cannot be combined with providing user credentials_ (`.UserName`, `.Password`), i.e you cannot directly launch an elevated process with a given (usually different) user identity. Here, the idea behind providing credentials may be to _bypass UAC_, which is (sensibly) not supported either.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: There is no need to use different credentials: just combine `.Verb = "RunAs"` with `.UseShellExecute = true`, and the UAC dialog will do the rest (mere _confirmation_ if the current user is an administrator or prompt for an _administrator's password_ ). Of course, the alternative is to launch the C# application _from an already elevated session_ (which the application could enforce).

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you need to check the powershell commands/scripts first.

Then you need to know that the admin permissions are not mandatory to control vms. [You can grant any user or group the required rights to control vms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/virtual_pc_guy/allowing-non-administrators-to-control-hyper-v).

Then you can redirect the standard output instead of using an intermediate file (Microsoft sample below):

```
      p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;  
      p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;  
      p.StartInfo.FileName = "Write500Lines.exe";  
      p.Start();  

      // To avoid deadlocks, always read the output stream first and then wait.  
      string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();  
      p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Note:

- If the intent behind the unsupported attempt to supply credentials programmatically via `.UserName` and `.Password` *in combination with creating an elevated process* (`.Verb = "RunAs"`) is to *bypass [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control)*, i.e. to avoid an interactive confirmation/authorization prompt, this *fundamentally won't work*, for security reasons.<sup>[1]</sup>
- Launching an *elevated* process may not even be necessary if you have the option to modify permissions to also allow non-administrators to control Hyper-V VMs - see [rotabor's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76859970/45375).

---

When using a [`ProcessStartInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo) instance to launch a process:

- `.Verb = "RunAs"` (starting a process *with elevation* (elevated privileges, as administrator) requires `.UseShellExecute = true`
- However, `.UseShellExecute = true` cannot be combined with `.UserName` and `.Password`

This means:

- **You can only launch an *elevated* process** (`.Verb = "RunAs"`, combined with `.UseShellExecute = true`) **as the *current* user.**

  - To launch an elevated process *as a different user*, you need *nested* processes:

    - A *non-elevated* helper process that you launch with the desired credentials. That is, omit `.Verb = "RunAs"`.
    - A nested, elevated process created in the context of the non-elevated process' user identity. Since you're calling PowerShell, you can use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process) `-Verb RunAs` in your PowerShell CLI call.<sup>[2]</sup>
- However, **you will ultimately *invariably* get a [UAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) dialog**.

  - That is, by design you can never bypass UAC *programmatically*, even if you supply an administrator's credentials.

    - Given that a [`SecureString`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Security.SecureString) instance must be used to supply the password ([`.Password`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.password)) programmatically and [given the limited security this type provides and that its use is not recommended in new code](https://github.com/dotnet/platform-compat/blob/master/docs/DE0001.md), using password-based credentials programmatically is best avoided.
  - If you still decide to specify administrator credentials programmatically, the only thing you gain is that the unavoidable UAC prompt becomes a mere *confirmation* prompt rather than having to provide an administrator's (username and) *password* when prompted.

---

<sup>[1] It is technically possible to *disable* UAC, but doing is strongly advised against, as it would leave your system highly vulnerable.</sup>

<sup>[2] `Start-Process` builds on the .NET `ProcessStartInfo` class, so it is subject to the same fundamental limitation: `-Verb RunAs` cannot be combined with `-Credential`.</sup>

Comment: thanks for your detailed information。 It's very important to me. as you said, it means there's no way to ignore UAC dialog. It's very bad when i want to start a vm , it will need confirm twice , it the vm is Off.

Comment: @goldii, hypothetically you can turn off UAC, though that would be very ill-advised. I think the answer now has all angles covered. Let us know if you think something's still missing.