# Group Policy for allowing users to install a service

Tags: c#, service, group-policy

I'm also search the web for this, but I'm curious if anyone is aware of a Group policy that allows a user to install a service and only Install services or potential install it through Group policy. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use something like elevating privilege

WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(accessToken);
WindowsImpersonationContext context = identity.Impersonate();

see thread:
[Elevating process privilege programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically)

Comment: Thanks, you know I had not thought of doing something like this.

Comment: So will elevating privileges allow me to install as a user without local admin or will I have to provide credentials to a administrator account?