# C# after starting a process, the process exits immediately

Tags: c#, process

I'm trying to run a process from my app (C#, only for Win7), but on many PCs the process starts and closes immediately (as seen in task manager) and on other PCs it starts fine. This is the code I use:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"c:\windows\system32\slui.exe");
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried reading from StandardError to see if there is a message?

Comment: If you launch slui.exe from the command prompt do you have an error ? It propably stop immediately because slui.exe failed

Comment: possible duplicate of [Elevating process privilege programatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically)

Comment: Why are you *not* using `ShellExecute`, yet setting the `Verb` property to `runas`?

Comment: Do you see any error in the application event log of windows?

Comment: I tried StandardError but there are no message.
If i launch slui.exe from cmd, app runs correctly.
The slui.exe gives an exit code 0.
I read the Elevating process subject and i set shellExecute true and verb="runas" but there no difference. 
There is now error or exception

Answer (score 6):

I am not familiar with slui.exe, but it could be that you need to set the WorkingDirectory property of the ProcessStartInfo instance.

Answer (score 0):

It's a permission problem. You probably need to set the [execution level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx) as "requireAdministrator"