# Access denied when attempt Configuration.Save() for installation in Program Files

Tags: c#, wpf, configurationmanager

Attempts to use `Configuration.Save()` fail when the WPF program is installed under "Program Files".  If installed elsewhere, the `Save()` works as expected.  Isn't the program itself authorized to edit its own .config file?

I get two exceptions:

```
System.Configuration: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Advanced Applications\ConfigurationTest\ejoqasrr.tmp' is denied. (C:\Program Files\Advanced Applications\ConfigurationTest\WPF.exe.Config)
mscorlib: Access to the path 'C:\Program Files\Advanced Applications\ConfigurationTest\ejoqasrr.tmp' is denied.
```

I tried opening with `ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming)` instead of `ConfigurationUserLevel.None` but it still failed, reporting different exceptions:

```
System.Configuration: An error occurred executing the configuration section handler for appSettings.
System.Configuration: ConfigurationSection properties cannot be edited when locked.
```

[NOTE: Searching found an article that appears related but didn't provide a resolution for this issue:
[Access to path denied for App.Config on Windows 8. How can I update App.Config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13701306/access-to-path-denied-for-app-config-on-windows-8-how-can-i-update-app-config)

The first two methods are called from MainVM and invoke the underlying base methods which expect to find a correlated property on the passed in object and then synchronize the appropriate values in AppSettings.

```
private void SettingsLoad()
{
    SettingsLoad(this);
}

private void SettingsSave()
{
    try
    {
        SettingsSave(this);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        currentMessageAction = MessageAction.Acknowledge;
        window.MessagePanel.Show("EXCEPTION!", Utility.ParseException(ex));
    }
}
....

public static void SettingsLoad(object main)
{
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    foreach (KeyValueConfigurationElement setting in config.AppSettings.Settings)
    {
        // Attempt to get a reference to the property and, if found, set its value
        var prop = main.GetType().GetProperty(setting.Key);
        if (prop != null)
        {
            prop.SetValue(main, setting.Value);
        }
    }
}

public static void SettingsSave(object main)
{
    var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
    foreach (KeyValueConfigurationElement setting in config.AppSettings.Settings)
    {
        // Attempt to get a reference to the property and, if found, update its value
        var prop = main.GetType().GetProperty(setting.Key);
        if (prop != null)
        {
            setting.Value = prop.GetValue(main).ToString();
        }
    }
    // This line produces an exception
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Isn't the program itself authorized to edit its own .config file?

No. The user account under which the application is running must have permissons to write to the folder/file.

Apparently it doesn't have the appropriate permissions to write to the "Program Files" folder in your case.

[How to Set File and Folder Permissions in Windows](https://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/set-file-folder-permissions-windows/)

Comment: I've decided to give you credit for the answer.  Though it didn't really answer the question I intended to ask it did answer the question I actually asked -- so, fair is fair. :-)  Further study led me to understand this didn't really work the way I thought it did so going another direction.