# Can I access files and Registry keys in the Windows Virtual Store, from a non-virtualized application?

Tags: c#, windows-7, uac, registry-virtualization

I have a 'legacy' XP application which writes files in the [ProgramFiles]\[Application] folder, and writes registry keys in the HKLM\Software\[Application] path.  When running the application in Windows Vista or Windows 7, the files and registry entries are written in the [Virtual Store](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884.aspx) instead.  That's fine; it doesn't break anything, yet.

Now, we've re-written the application in .NET.  It only reads and writes files in "safe," user-scoped locations, and we use an application manifest with `requestedExecutionLevel` specified, in order to disable registry virtualization.

When users upgrade to the latest version, we would like to maintain compatibility with our old application, by importing settings from the previously-virtualized files and registry settings.

So, the question: Is there a way to access the files and registry keys in the Virtual Store from an application that has `requestedExecutionLevel` specified in its manifest?

Comment: Obviously one option is to write a migration app that also runs virtualized so that it can read from the old and write to the new

Comment: Did you ever get an answer to this? I'm dealing with the exact same issue. My approach was going to build a migration app as well, but would hope there would by a different way of approaching this.

Comment: I did not get an answer.  The migration layer sounds like the only option at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I supposed I've left this question open long enough.  Here are my findings.

There does not appear to be any way to access both the Virtual Store and the 'real' registry and file-system from the same process.  The Virtual Store is applied automatically to Windows applications which do not specify the `requestedExecutionLevel`, and which are not launched "As Admin."

The answer, then, appears to be a specialized "migration" application.  This application *will not specify* the `requestedExecutionLevel`, thereby guaranteeing that the application will be placed into the "Virtual Store," when launched without administrative privileges.  The application operates in 2-stages:

1. Launch the application *without* administrative access.  The application will read the desired registry keys and file-system files from the Virtual Store, and save them in some temporary (non-virtualized) location like the user's AppData directory.
2. Re-launch the application *with* administrative access.  The application could actually [do this for itself, automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically), to streamline the process.  The application will now have access to the "real" registry and file system.  The application will save the registry keys and files which backed-up from the Virtual Store, saving them to the desired 'real' location.

This application would ideally be somewhat generic, accepting any user-specified registry keys and files as input arguments during launch.