# Start Process as Administrator, without UseShellExecute?

Tags: c#, process

So here is my issue:

I have start a .bin file, which is just a .exe, renamed to .bin, with administrator privileges.

Here is what I have:

```
PSI.FileName = "Client.bin";
PSI.WorkingDirectory = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
PSI.UseShellExecute = false;
PSI.Verb = "runas";
Process.Start(PSI);
```

I also have the requireAdministrator set in the manifest.

I have to set UseShellExecute to false, seeing is that is the only way I can find that starts the .bin as a .exe. However, according [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163486.aspx), runas, and the manifest only are used when UseShellExecute is set to true.

Question: How to start a non .exe process, with elevated privileges?

Comment: So, why can't you use ShellExecute? If the file is a valid PE executable, it doesn't matter what the file extension is.

Comment: Why not rename the file?

Comment: Check out the app manifest file, you can specify that your app requires elevated permissions. As a result, any process that you start from within your application should then run with elevated permissions, if I remember correctly.

Comment: If you set UseShellExecute, it tries to just start the file, as if you were double clicking it. So, because no file association exists for .bin file, there is an exception.
@Jason, that only is taken into account when ShellExecute is true.
Also, can't rename the file, it's for a client, and it "isn't possible"

Answer (score 0):

Have a parent process which is a executable with administrative privilege & then launch the ".bin" file from it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20872219/4588884) this is not possible to run .bin file with elevation directly.

At least you can run your own .exe with `runas` (and ShellExecute = true) and order it with commandline to run .tmp (without ShellExecute, but the process is already elevated) and die. But this is the "last chance" solution.