# How to run msi installer in cmd as admin using C#

Tags: c#, process, cmd, admin

I have an msi installer that I need to install it silently from the C#

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\temp\";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "msiexec /quiet /i Setup.msi ADDLOCAL=test";
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit(60000);
```

noting that the cmd command is working fine if I manually run it from the cmd as admin

when I run it I just get the cmd screen in admin mode but the command does not executing

Comment: What is your problem with this code? Any error message?

Comment: Please check this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16926232/run-process-as-administrator-from-a-non-admin-application

Comment: when I run it I just get the cmd screen in admin mode but the command does not executing

Comment: I knew that but I need to install the msi silently

Comment: Why won't you just run msiexec instead of cmd? And just in case you can set WindowStyle to Hidden.

Comment: yeah but I get en exception : The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: I think you need to mention full path of msi

Comment: you need to mention full path of msi    process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format(" /qb /i \"{0}\" ALLUSERS=1", sMSIPath);

Comment: @V2Solutions-MSTeam , I did that but it's still the same I just get the cmd runs as admin nothing else , could you please check the example above and edit it ?

Comment: I guess you need to quote the parameter string in `Arguments`. Otherwise the parameters are interpreted as parameters to `cmd.exe`, not to `msiexec`.

Comment: like this ?
"msiexec //quiet //i Setup.msi ADDLOCAL=test"

Comment: No, like `"\"msiexec ...\""`.

Comment: unfortunately that did not work also !

Comment: I have checked your code but I got error cannot find file specified.  Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexe.exe";
           // process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\temp\";
            string path = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\Setup1.msi";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = "msiexec /quiet /i " + path;
            process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit(60000);

Comment: even I changed the Setup1.msi locations

Comment: Oh, as discussed here multiple times, `GetCurrentDirectory` does not necessarily return the directory you think! Depending on how and from where you start you application, this may differ from the directory the `exe` resides in!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

as V2Solutions - MS Team mentioned , the solution is to change the following

```
process.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexe.exe"
```

and the code will be

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec";
process.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\temp\";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = " /quiet /i Setup.msi ADDLOCAL=test";
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit(60000);
```

this works for me :)

Answer (score 5):

This is also going to help you:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo.FileName = "msiexec.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = string.Format("/qn /i \"{0}\" ALLUSERS=1", @"somepath\msiname.msi");
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: The string.Format was the missing piece for me