# run cmd with os.system as Administrator

Tags: python, windows, date, privileges

I am trying to run date command with cmd, but I required to be an Administrator in order to do so. The command is: `os.system("date 09/09/1999")`

Is it possible to run the command with admin privileges without the need to import new libraries?

Comment: Operating System?  API?

Comment: "without the need to import new libraries" - probably not. On Unix, you'd need to call `sudo` to gain administrative privileges, on Windows you'd need to hook into UAC which I believe only happens automatically for programs marked to run as administrator, elevating privileges for an existing process might require an API call assuming it's possible.

Comment: How it can be done with win32 api ?

Comment: Start here: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/search/en-US?query=uac&refinement=117 and search for how to do the stuff you find programatically.

Comment: ([`runas` might work](http://stackoverflow.com/a/133500/41655).)

Comment: Also note that you could (outside of python), do runas to start a cmd shell as adminstrator [e.g. start->run->accessories-> right click cmd and select run as) and then start python from there, depending on how you're invoking your script)

Comment: Thank you, Foon option worked