# Windows service throws "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied" when starting

Tags: c#, windows-services

A customer has reported an issue where they are unable to start our service. Looking through the logs I can see lots of `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied` exceptions:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Cannot open *ServiceName* service on computer '.'. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
    at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServiceHandle(Int32 desiredAccess)
    at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
    at BackupStack.InterApp.ServiceStarter.startService(Boolean useShellExec)
Cannot open BackupStack service on computer '.'.
    at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.GetServiceHandle(Int32 desiredAccess)
    at System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController.Start(String[] args)
    at BackupStack.InterApp.ServiceStarter.startService(Boolean useShellExec)
System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Access is denied
Access is denied
```

The obvious thing to check was that the user has permission to start the service. They're in the administrative group. When they try to start the service from our application they are prompted by the UAC, but nothing happens. It fails to start.

Side note: Our application provides a way to restart / reinstall the service if it is not running. We make use of [`ProcessStartInfo.Verb = "runas"`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically) to elevate the process that starts the service.

They are unable to start the service from `services.msc`, as well as from our application.

The only other clues I have is they've reported this error appearing in a dialogue box:

> Error 1053: The service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion.

Our service is running under the `Local System Account` and targets `.NET 2.0`.

Has anyone got any ideas what I can check to understand where it might be failing? I believe they have the correct permissions, but I may be wrong. If anyone knows all the places to check for this, that would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "service did not respond to the start or control request in a timely fashion" message usually is caused by the "OnStart" method of the service takes too long to complete (usually 20 or 30 seconds). If you put too much startup code into that method - i.e. network access code, database access code - this is a quite normal response. It usually happens when you try to initialize something from a database and the database isn't ready or too slow to respond. I'd check that any dependent services are up and running.

With Administrtive rights *and* elevated process rights they should be able to start/stop just about any service. But depending on what is failing inside the service, this still might be a "secondary" error code...