# HTML and ActiveX launch .exe files from control panel, etc

Tags: c#, javascript, html, internet-explorer, activex

I am trying to launch some .exe files from the windows directory in HTML using activeX, here is the link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc144191(VS.85).aspx

I know this might sound stupid or something, but I am going to open these HTML via C# web browser tool as it uses the IE engine.

It opens some of the .exe files from the link i provided up. for instance : C:\windows\system32\control.exe , but i try something more sensitive like c:\windows\system32\RecoveryDrive.exe , it simply does not works, i get an error.

Here is the HTML code I use. Thanks!

```
<body>
<p><h1>This is my web page</h1></p>
<button align="center" type=button onclick="ControlPanel();">Control Panel</button></p>
<button align="center" type=button onclick="RecoveryDrive();">MAGIC</button></p>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function ControlPanel()
    {
        var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        ws.Exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\control.exe");
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
    function RecoveryDrive()
    {
        var ws = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        ws.Exec("c:\\windows\\system32\\RecoveryDrive.exe");
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to execute applications that require elevated privileges, your application must do one of two things:

1: Run with elevated privileges. When you invoke a process, it will see that you are already using elevated privileges and run at the same level.

-or-

2: Create a launcher executable that requires elevated privileges. From the launcher, start the application that needs this privilege level. [See this SO answer for more information about process privilege elevation.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programatically)

**HOWEVER**

Doing this from a web browser complicates things as all web browsers are [sandboxed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandbox_%28computer_security%29) to prevent malicious code from executing. You will have to put this web site in IE's Trusted Zone to even launch a non-privileged executable.

Comment: But how do add the .html files to the trusted zone on the C# web browser?