# Process.Start never returns when UAC denied

Tags: c#, winforms, uac, process.start

I have an updater exe that is meant to close the primary exe, replace it with an updated exe, and then launch that updated exe. When the updater attempts to start the updated exe, if the UAC permissions dialog is denied by the user, the updater will hang. This is because the `Process.Start()` function never returns. My CPU cycles meter indicates practically no usage btw.

I would hope all my users just say "yes" to the UAC, but since I'm here I'd like to handle this case with some kind of error message at least. Assume my users will have at least Windows 7. The exes themselves are 32 bit Winforms applications. Targeted .Net Framework is 4.0. Using Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

Any ideas on how to detect for when my user declines the UAC dialog?

I'm guessing all I can do is make the `Process.Start()` run on a separate thread that will timeout after a while. For more code:

```
private void RestartProcess()
{
    ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    startInfo.FileName = @"C:\Users\Me\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\updated.exe";
    MessageBox.Show("Attempting to start process");
    Process newProc = Process.Start(startInfo);
    MessageBox.Show("If this shows, the user has clicked YES in the UAC.");
}
```

**Solution:**

`Process.Start()`exits silently with a Win32Exception unless one uses a Try{}Catch{} block to catch the error.

Comment: I assume (based on what you indicated above) that you know when a user clicks "Yes" on the UAC dialog, right?  If you know this, why not use the [DialogResult Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) to handle the case of a "No"?

Comment: Did you try tinkering with the [Manifest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb756929.aspx)? Don't even give the users the chance to say No.

Comment: The bottleneck is the call to Process.Start(). When the user clicks "Yes" everything works out fine. When the user clicks "No" the function never returns, so there's nothing to handle.

Comment: @ Jason Goemaat Provided more code.

Comment: Try `startInfo.Verb = "runas";`

Comment: @CSharpie How would that help? The UAC dialog is already being shown.

Comment: @CSharpie Tried setting the startInfo.Verb to "runas"; same behavior.

Comment: What OS is this? Are all apps x64?

Comment: @TYH Not yet. I'll check into that since I'm not familiar with the Manifest.

Comment: @rene - Yes, that is true.  The point I was making however is that he knows when "Yes" is clicked.

Comment: @rene Interesting rene. Are you starting the exe from another exe? I'm not getting any errors from the updater which was itself started by the primary exe. Considering the differences between our platforms, any idea why you'd get an error and mine would only hang?

Comment: @rene My target framework is .Net 4.0 using Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
   Process newProc = Process.Start(startInfo);
   MessageBox.Show("If this shows, the user has clicked YES in the UAC.");
```

This is normal, the exception that's raised by Process.Start() will bypass the MessageBox.Show() call.  It is a Win32Exception for Windows error code 1223, ERROR_CANCELLED, "The operation was cancelled by the user".

Clearly you'll want to avoid swallowing exceptions here.

Comment: Perfect. All that was required was a simple try catch statement. My thanks, Mr. Passant.