# C#: How to catch the exception when user refuses to grant elevated privileges?

Tags: c#, exception, uac, win32exception

In my C# code I have roughly this:

```
    public void RunCommand()
    {
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
            "notepad.exe")
        {
            UseShellExecute = true,
            Verb = "Runas",
        };
        var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
        process.WaitForExit(1000);
    }
```

When run, this prompts the user to grant elevated privileges. If the user refuses, the call throws a **Win32Exception** with the text "The operation was cancelled by the user".

I want to catch this exception specifically, i.e., tell it apart from other exceptions. I want to be able to know that the user has cancelled.

Can I be reasonably confident that when a **Win32Exception** is thrown, it is probably this? Or can the call throw **Win32Exception** for all sorts of other reasons? I don't want to start string matching on the error message, since that presumably varies depending on user settings...

Comment: It seems you have already tried it. Why should the exception type change? If it fails, does it really matter why it failed? I could think of other problems like FileNotFound, if `notepad.exe` is not available.

Comment: I don't expect the exception type to _change_, but I expect that this call might throw **Win32Exception** for all sorts of other reasons. So if I catch **Win32Exception**, I'm not confident that it was due to user cancellation.

Comment: Check if the `Win32Exception.ErrorCode` is 1223 to be sure.

Comment: [Process.Start never returns when UAC denied](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23350175/7444103)

Comment: _"Check if the Win32Exception.ErrorCode is 1223 to be sure."_ - See also 0x0...4C7 (1223 in Hex) in [Win32 Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-erref/18d8fbe8-a967-4f1c-ae50-99ca8e491d2d)

Comment: In my case I get error code -2147467259.

Comment: That's the generic (`0x80004005`) *Access denied* exception (`HRESULT`).

Comment: What is the difference between 1223 and -2147467259? Do both of them indicate that the application failed to get elevated permissions?

Comment: The error codes are documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes). `1223` is ERROR_CANCELLED.

Comment: There's a macro to map a Win32 error to a `HRESULT`. It's probably in the documentation already linked (if you're interested)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up doing this, which seems to work on my system:

```
    public void RunCommand()
    {
        var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(
            "notepad.exe")
        {
            UseShellExecute = true,
            Verb = "Runas",
        };
        var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);
        process.WaitForExit(1000);
    }
    catch (Win32Exception e)
    {
        if (e.ErrorCode == 1223 || e.ErrorCode == -2147467259)
            // Throw easily recognizable custom exception.
            throw new ElevatedPermissionsDeniedException("Unable to get elevated privileges", e);
        else
            throw;
    }
```