# Executing Powershell Scripts from C# or Dynamics NAV2013

Tags: c#, powershell-3.0, dynamics-nav

I have now tried about a hundred ways of automating the execution of powershell scripts from C# and Dynamics NAV 2013.

Running the script works 100% from either Powershell ISE or executing it with the following command in commandline:

```
powershell.exe -version 3.0 -command ". 'C:\temp\script.ps1'"
```

So the last option I tried now was to put this all in a .bat file and execute the .bat file using System.Diagnostics.Process (also, executing the .bat file manually works 100%)

```
Setup.GET;
ProcessInfo := ProcessInfo.ProcessStartInfo(FileName); //The .bat File
ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute := FALSE;
ProcessInfo.RedirectStandardError := TRUE;

//<< Credentials
ProcessInfo.Domain := Setup.Domain;
ProcessInfo.UserName := Setup.Username;

SecurePwd := SecurePwd.SecureString();

FOR i := 1 TO STRLEN(Setup.Password) DO
  SecurePwd.AppendChar(Setup.Password[i]);

ProcessInfo.Password := SecurePwd;
//>> Credentials

Process := Process.Start(ProcessInfo);
StreamReader := Process.StandardError();

MESSAGE(StreamReader.ReadToEnd());
```

Without setting the credentials I get as output from the message:

```
The handle is invalid.
The handle is invalid.
The handle is invalid.
The handle is invalid.
The handle is invalid.
Set-ExecutionPolicy : Access to the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\1\ShellIds\Microsoft.PowerShell' is denied.
```

And it just about complains about something on every line in the script.

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'D:\psmodules\Multitenancy\NAVMultitenancySamples.psm1' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
```

etc. etc.

With the credentials filled in, message is blank but it didn't do anything that it was supposed to.

Now, from the message I can see that it is trying to access the registry entries for Powershell version 1 instead of 3... could that be part of the problem?
Version 3 is installed:

```
PS C:\> $Host.Version

Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
3      0      -1     -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the UAC side of things? It may require UAC privileges, as opposed to just Admin credentials;

[This other StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133500/168457) details how to elevate a System.Diagnostics.Process command;

```
startInfo.Verb = "runas";
```

Comment: UAC is turned off.

Added as suggested:

`ProcessInfo.Verb := 'runas';`

Switched `ProcessInfo.UseShellExecute := TRUE;`

(removed the credentials) 
returns:
`A call to System.Diagnostics.Process.Start failed with this message: Access is denied`

Put credentials back and switch UseShellExecute off, returned nothing from the StandardError, only an ExitCode = -1073741502

Comment: Exit Codes apparently don't work very well from Powershell, only verifying by checking the output manually -- does StandardOutput have any information?

Comment: StandardOutput is also blank.

Comment: By adding my own exit codes, I narrowed it down that powershell "hangs" on an Import-Module command. As mentioned previously running it manually works. 

So I thought it might have to do with the folder permissions where the module its trying to import resides, granted full access to the executing user - still nothing.

Comment: I assume you're running with the credentials the same as your current user? The user has permissions to those Import-Module paths? Any extra info with the -Verbose command ?

Comment: That was indeed part of the issue. Somehow, because my NAV service was running on NETWORK SERVICE, even though I was passing admin credentials to Process.Start it tried to authenticate accessing/importing the scripts with NETWORK SERVICE. Changed my service to run with network admin credentials and it was working :)

Thanks for the assistance!!