# Elevating privileges programmatically under Linux environment with C# .NET core

Tags: c#, .net, linux, process, .net-core

How do I elevate privileges programmatically under Linux environment when I spawn a Process? For Windows console applications, it can be done by setting `startInfo.Verb = "runas";` according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programmatically). However, that does not work under Linux environment.

For example, I want to have a Process that can create, delete, edit, move to, move from, etc, in the root directory. How can I elevate the privilege so all subsequent process call and not require the user to input their password?

Comment: This is subverting the Linux security system, I'm not sure it is possible. The main process should have been started with `sudo` or `su <admin user>`. How are you moving the files? Using external processes or `File.Copy`?

Comment: @RonBeyer I am moving the files with mv command `proc.StartInfo.FileName = cmd`