# COM object run as elevated privileges in C#

Tags: c#, .net, comobject

Currently I am calling [ADMT](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=56570) COM object in C# with the following code.

```
            Type admtMigration = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("ADMT.Migration",true);
            dynamic admt = Activator.CreateInstance(admtMigration);
            IList<MethodInfo> props = new List<MethodInfo>(admtMigration.GetMethods());
```

However It also requires **elevated privileges**. Running VS 2017 in administrator mode I can debug the application, but after deploying the DLL, 
the Code throws error.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programmatically) question, and I can't user **Application Manifest File** for permission,

also I can't decorate my class with

`[PrincipalPermission(SecurityAction.Demand, Role = @"BUILTIN\Administrators")]`

since it is throwing error at application runtime.

**Any Idea how can I run COM object with elevated privileges in C#.**

Comment: The app that uses this COM object must run elevated.  Why this app can't user a manifest is quite unclear.  You can create a shortcut to the app on the desktop and tick its "Run as administrator" checkbox in the Advanced properties.

Comment: @HansPassant this is class library which will act as connector for the main application, the main application itself will not run elevated (This is not my choice). I am searching anything by which I can run only my class library project with elevated privilege, I don't even know if this is possible or not.