# Writing to a newly created command prompt window using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, command-prompt

I'm trying to use command prompt as an admin using vb.net and I'm opening it by using runas in the default cmd.exe file. I want to then run commands through the newly opened command prompt window running as the domain admin using vb.net. How do I go about doing this?

This is the method that I'm using:

```
Public Sub runCmd(ByVal pass As String, ByVal command As String, ByVal arguments As String, ByVal permanent As Boolean)
    Dim p As Process = New Process()
    Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
    pi.Arguments = " "+ If(permanent = True, "/K", "/C") + " " + command + " " + arguments
    pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    p.StartInfo = pi
    p.Start()
End Sub
```

This is the call that opens cmd:

```
runCmd(strPass, "runas", "/user:<domain>\" + strUser + " cmd", False)
```

Comment: Some options discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `Verb` property of the `StartInfo` to `"runas"`.

```
Public Sub runCmd(ByVal pass As String, ByVal command As String, ByVal arguments As String, ByVal permanent As Boolean)
    Dim p As Process = New Process()
    Dim pi As ProcessStartInfo = New ProcessStartInfo()
    pi.Arguments = " " + If(permanent = True, "/K", "/C") + " " + command + " " + arguments
    pi.FileName = "cmd.exe"
    pi.Verb = "runas"
    p.StartInfo = pi
    p.Start()
End Sub
```

And you then call your function like this:

```
runCmd(strPass, "", "/user:<domain>\" + strUser, False)
```

Comment: That just opens the command window, how do I run commands through it

Comment: The window doesn't stay open, it just flashes open and then immediately closes

Comment: @Adam - That is normal if the `permanent` argument is set to `False`. For the window to stay opened, the `permanent` argument has to be set to `True`. This is how you have written your `runCmd` `Sub`.