# C#, Task Scheduler with high privileges

Tags: c#

I need to create a task in Task Scheduler with high privileges, but the function only takes 3 parameters...

```
TaskService.Instance.AddTask("Test Task",  new BootTrigger() , new ExecAction("C:\\myapp.exe");
```

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Elevating process privilege programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programmatically)

Answer (score 1):

Presuming that you are referring to the [.NET wrapper for the Windows Task Scheduler](https://github.com/dahall/TaskScheduler), you should first use `TaskService.Instance.NewTask()` to create an instance of the task, and then configure it as explained in the [examples](https://github.com/dahall/TaskScheduler/wiki/Examples) section.

Something like:

```
var td = TaskService.Instance.NewTask();
...
td.Settings.Priority = System.Diagnostics.ProcessPriorityClass.Normal;
td.Triggers.Add(new BootTrigger());
td.Actions.Add(new ExecAction("C:\\myapp.exe"));
...

TaskService.Instance.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("MyTask", td);
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved :)

```
TaskDefinition td = TaskService.Instance.NewTask();
td.RegistrationInfo.Description = "Does something";
td.Principal.RunLevel = TaskRunLevel.Highest;        
BootTrigger bt = new BootTrigger();
bt.Delay = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
td.Triggers.Add(bt);
td.Actions.Add("C:/Users/myapp.exe");
TaskService.Instance.RootFolder.RegisterTaskDefinition("Test", td);
```