# How can I create a windows application that should run with admin rights in .Net C# without prompting UAC again and again?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, uac

I am developing a windows application in .Net C#. The application is using some third party drivers which requires admin rights for it's execution. I know we can use app manifest and provide the required privilege there, but it prompts UAC everytime when user runs the application which is annoying for the user. So, Is there any other way so that we can run the application without prompting the user or it only prompts once and when user runs the application next time it should run with admin rights.

Thanks

Comment: if your app needs admin-rights, you *have* to provide the appropriate credentials. That's the entire point of UAC. If you could bypass it, you could easily hack into every system with admin-rights. Never wondered why installing something on a windows-machine allways promts you for those credentials?

Comment: If you are running a service than start the service with Admin rights.

Answer (score 0):

This task can be delegated to a **shortcut** to an executable file in the properties of which the *"Run as Administrator"* flag is set.
Learn more about programmatic process privilege elevation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programmatically).
P. S. Applications that can run themselves as admin without asking administrator rights exists and are called rootkits, backdoors or trojans. Such programs are malicious. Writing them is a tricky and sometimes illegal.

Comment: To be just a little more clear because I just argued and demoed this with an obstinate person.  If the thing doing the launching has admin, then all the stuff it launches inherit those permissions.  I have a "smorgasbord installer" that requires admin.  It has buttons for each of the drivers the user might need.  When they click the button it extracts to %temp% and then launches them.  UAC happens exactly once on the outermost smorgasbord installer.  A shortcut can require admin.  Lots of installer technologies let you require admin.