# Extract zip file to C:\ProgramFiles\Folder c#

Tags: c#, .net, zip, extract, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I have written code to extract zip file to C:\Program Files. But its giving unauthorized access.
Please help. Its the requirement. I cant change the folder also.

Code:

```
ZipFile.ExtractToDirectory(archiveFileName, "C:\\Program Files");
```

Comment: Normally, ```c:\Program Files``` tend to be restricted to Admins only.  Pick a different path or ensure that ```c:\Program files``` is r/w to the user account.   Best option actually is to use a different path.

Comment: Code is the above. I cant change path. Its the requirement

Comment: You can test if you are an admin, or just catch the exception, then prompt to restart with elevated permissions (`startInfo.Verb = "runas";`) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programmatically.

Comment: You will need to have your app be running as an admin; no one else can write to that location. There's no way around that. Is there a rationale for that _requirement_?

Comment: I tried the following                    
  pro.Verb = "runas";
          pro.Arguments = "x \"" + @"C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Temp\123.zip" + "\" -o" + @"C:\Program Files";
        Process x = Process.Start(pro);
        x.WaitForExit();   But it not extracting neither giving exception

Comment: With regards to @ewong's answer, **do not** make `c:/Program File` writable to non-admins. Doing so would open a big security hole in that system