# How to rename machine/computer name through c#

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am making a program that will be used for a small invetoring project. This program is to be used from the staff to get their basic info (computer name, monitor name etc.) and I am trying to add the option to rename the computer into a new template based on a table.

The problem that I seem to have is that to rename the machine the user needs admin privileges (to be expected of course as it is the safe thing to do). So what I try to do is to request the credentials when the program has done all other things and only thing left is the renaming of the computer and try impersonate the admin in some way. I need to note here the program is to be run while the user is logged in and everything will be handle by the admins.

What I try to do is the following:

```
try
{
    ConnectionOptions connectionOptions = new ConnectionOptions
    {
        Username = admin,
        Password = password,
        Authority = $"NTLMDOMAIN:DOMAIN"
    };
    ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope($@"\\{Environment.MachineName}\root\cimv2", connectionOptions);

    // Create an instance of the ManagementObjectSearcher
    using (ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_ComputerSystem")))
    {
        // Get the first instance (there should be only one)
        ManagementObjectCollection collection = searcher.Get();
        foreach (ManagementObject obj in collection)
        {
            // Set the new computer name
            obj["Name"] = newComputerName;

            // Apply the changes
            obj.InvokeMethod("Rename", null);
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Computer renamed to: {newComputerName}");
}
catch (UnauthorizedAccessException)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Access denied. Make sure you have the necessary permissions.");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
}
```

What I get from this is "Error: User credentials cannot be used for local connections"

Then I found that if I manually open Powershell as admin and run the following command, I can get to rename the computer after a "windows powershell credential request":

```
Rename-Computer -NewName "newNameHere" -DomainCredential domainHere\adminHere
```

So I tried running the command through c# with the following script but I get "Error Code 5 (Access Denied)", which I think it should be the case as I dont get the "windows powershell credential request" window to pass the password.

```
static void RunCommandWithAdminPrivileges(string username, SecureString password)
{
    string commandToRun = "Rename-Computer -NewName \"newNameHere\" -DomainCredential domainHere\\adminHere";

    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "powershell.exe",
        Arguments = $"-Command {commandToRun}",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Domain = "Domain",
        Verb = "runas",
        UserName = username,
        Password = password
    };

    using (Process process = new Process { StartInfo = psi })
    {
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine("Output: " + output);
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + error);
    }
}
```

I tried running also the following which is similiar to the first script just without the credentials which of course I get again "Error Code 5 (Access Denied)":

```
static void ChangeComputerName(string newComputerName)
{
    using (ManagementObject win32ComputerSystem = new ManagementObject("Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='" + System.Environment.MachineName + "'"))
    {
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = win32ComputerSystem.GetMethodParameters("Rename");
        inParams["Name"] = newComputerName;

        ManagementBaseObject outParams = win32ComputerSystem.InvokeMethod("Rename", inParams, null);

        uint returnValue = (uint)outParams["ReturnValue"];
        //uint returnValue = 666;
        if (returnValue != 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to change computer name. Error code: {returnValue}");
        }
    }
}
```

Tried also to run everything under this impersonator I found in [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User) but I got nothing different so there must be something I am missing on my part.

Comment: `to rename the machine the user needs admin privileges` yes, and there's no way to bypass it, thank goodness. That's a *major* change that changes the computer's name on the network and DNS. It's unclear why you want a C# program for this either. You already found `Rename-Computer` which does what you want and can target other machines. The machine name can be specified through DHCP too. When setting up a new machine an administrator can create answer files that set new machine names automatically

Comment: `after a "windows powershell credential request":` in other words, admin privileges

Comment: `to get their basic info (computer name, monitor name etc.) and I am trying to add the option to rename the computer into a new template based on a table.` you don't need an application for this either. WMI was built for remote administration. Anything you can request locally using WMI you can also request remotely. `Rename-Computer` has a `-ComputerName` parameter that allows you to target another computer. Software like Windows Admin Center can do all this and more with a nice UI

Comment: Also why use `powershell.exe` you can call it direct from C#using `Powershell.Create`

Comment: Using proper tools for this would not only be the optimal thing but also the obvious and safest. Unfortunately my options are to either change the code such as the admin can do the renaming through the script itself by passing the credentials on demand or if that flops then prompt him with the powershell command to do the 2 extra steps themselves and report the result back to the script. The whole process was going to be a 100% manual thing, I am trying to lessen the workload while avoiding possible user errors as much as possible with the means given to me.

Comment: @Charlieface I did a back and forth on .net framework and core so I skipped having two references for it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133379/elevating-process-privilege-programmatically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out(sort of) so I am posting an answer for anyone who might be helped from this. I will say that as stated from other users in the comments I don't really suggest doing this using a "dumb script" but go for tools that are ment for this kind of needs.

First I use a manifest for requiring the admin verification from UAC as stated in another answer in this post. Better use as many tools you are provided than try to replicate them.

The biggest issue was how to run powershell with admin rights properly through C#. Using "runas" for admin execute while passing Username and Password seems to not work as you would expect (my guess would be that this happens for the better, but I haven't delved into it yet). So by requiring a UAC admin at the start you ensure that you can skip the credentials and change the function as seen below

```
static void RunCommandWithAdminPrivileges(string username, SecureString password)
{
    string commandToRun = "Rename-Computer -NewName \"newNameHere\" -DomainCredential domainHere\\adminHere";

    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "powershell.exe",
        Arguments = $"-Command {commandToRun}",
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        CreateNoWindow = true,
        Domain = "Domain",
        Verb = "runas"
    };

    using (Process process = new Process { StartInfo = psi })
    {
        process.Start();
        process.WaitForExit();

        string output = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        string error = process.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

        Console.WriteLine("Output: " + output);
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " + error);
    }
}
```

Probably you could use the more C# way, but I haven't gotten around in testing it

```
static void ChangeComputerName(string newComputerName)
{
    using (ManagementObject win32ComputerSystem = new ManagementObject("Win32_ComputerSystem.Name='" + System.Environment.MachineName + "'"))
    {
        ManagementBaseObject inParams = win32ComputerSystem.GetMethodParameters("Rename");
        inParams["Name"] = newComputerName;

        ManagementBaseObject outParams = win32ComputerSystem.InvokeMethod("Rename", inParams, null);

        uint returnValue = (uint)outParams["ReturnValue"];

        if (returnValue != 0)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Failed to change computer name. Error code: {returnValue}");
        }
    }
}
```

You need to keep in mind that both functions don't seem to work under VPN as the Domain cannot be recognized. Manually changing the name of the computer with the UAC prompt works, but it does not with my methods(or at least not they way I am using them). I don't really mind that so I haven't searched for a fix but something to note if you want this functionality.

Also I "suggest" running the whole app with
`shift+righ click -> "run a different user"` to avoid access issues with local admins or you can use, if you really have to(but my guess that this is even riskier security wise), something like an [Impersonator](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10090/A-small-C-Class-for-impersonating-a-User) depending what you want to do.

Finally I repeat that this whole thing is not the way to approach handling the devices in your network. Try using proper tools as much as possible, especially if what you try to do meddles with security.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe elevating your application's privileges would solve your issue

Add a `manifest` with the current tag

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />
```

Comment: I tried this but it doesn't seem to change anything. What I understand the issue to be is how I am trying to access the actual windows tools to do the renaming for me.