# How to not use hardcoded credentials

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms

I have a Winforms C# program that I implemented using VS. The program is there to run processes as admin. Until now the credentials are hardcoded.

But I ask myself, wouldn't it be possible to get an input prompt at building the building process.

It's no problem that the credentials are in the built program but I do not want to save the credentials in the source code.

So I thought there must be a way that at build process VS asks for username and password.

Is this possible?

Comment: Why at build? Why not at runtime? Sounds like a walking, talking security breach.

Comment: When you say, "The program is there to run processes as admin" are you doing this with `Process.Start`? If so, have you looked into the [runas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/133500/5438626) argument?

Comment: Why not at runtime? Because the user does not know about the credentials?

Comment: And for runas I do not need any credentials? Sorry that was not the question. I know what I want to do. What I have written.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to prompt the user for credentials during the build process and save them to the application configuration file.

Project structure:

[image]

First, you could add an appSettings node to your application's configuration file (such as app.config or web.config) to save the credential information:

```xml
<appSettings>
   <add key="Username" value=""/>
   <add key="Password" value=""/>
</appSettings>
```

Then, create a simple form to prompt the user for their username and password and save it to a configuration file:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourNamespace
{
     public partial class LoginForm : Form
     {
         public LoginForm()
         {
             InitializeComponent();
         }

         private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
             
             string username = txtUsername.Text;
             string password = txtPassword.Text;

             //Save credentials to configuration file
             SaveCredentials(username, password);

          
             this.Close();
         }

         private void SaveCredentials(string username, string password)
         {
             //Update username and password in configuration file
             Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
             config.AppSettings.Settings["Username"].Value = username;
             config.AppSettings.Settings["Password"].Value = password;
             config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
             ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
         }
     }
}
```

When your application starts, first check if the username and password exist in the configuration file.If it does not exist, display the login window:

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace YourNamespace
{
     static class Program
     {
         [STAThread]
         static void Main()
         {
             Application.EnableVisualStyles();
             Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

            
             string username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Username"];
             string password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Password"];

             if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(username) || string.IsNullOrEmpty(password))
             {
                
                 LoginForm loginForm = new LoginForm();
                 Application.Run(loginForm);
             }
             else
             {
                 
                 Application.Run(new Form1());
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Hope it could be helpful.

Comment: Where does the InitializeComponent() function come from?

Comment: I've added my test project structure in the answer. In a C# Windows Forms application, the `InitializeComponent()` function is generated automatically by Visual Studio when you create a new form or user control using the Windows Forms Designer. This function initializes all the controls, layout settings, and event handlers defined in the form or user control.

Comment: ah ok.

But I think you totally missunderstood me.
I don't want that the user get prompted for credentials. I want to get prompted when I build the app, didn't i write that?

The other thing is. I don't want to save credentials in settings or elswhere, i want to use them in my app but instaead of hardcoding them i want to get prompted for them while the build process, so that i don't have to save them in the source code.